# Proof of equality of integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

I'm currently sitting on the following problem:

Let f be in the set of the integrable functions(:=$L^¹(\mathbb{R}^n))$, A $\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ invertible. Therefore define g:=$\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $g(x) := f(Ax+b)$. Show that $g \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}g(x)dx = \frac{1}{|detA|}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(y) dy$$

The proof for $g \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$  shouldn't be a problem, because g should still be continuous. The only thing I don't get for the integral: I know I could just substitute $Ax+b$ but I have no idea where $\frac{1}{|detA|}$ would come from?

Comment: Glad to be of help. I'll make it an answer to avoid the spread of answers in comments. Edit: Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y=Ax+b$ then $dy = |\det A| \,dx$ or $dx = (|\det A|)^{-1} \, dy$.

Answer (score 0):

$x \in R^n$,so you should do a transition $y=Ax+b$ to calculate  $\int_{R^n} g(x) d x$,and then $det|A|$ is the jacobian.